# Wireshark Problem in Ubuntu [Mininet]

Tags: software-installation

I have a problem in mininet, I want to start Wireshark but it displays this message:

```
Error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Gtk-WARNING**: cannot open display
Exit 1 sudo wireshark
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly you started Wireshark with `sudo wireshark`. A detailed answer to similar problem is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/467994/457662). In short you should execute:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR wireshark
```

Because typing it each time might be cumbersome, you should consider adding a shell alias to your environment. For bash add this to `.bashrc`:

```
alias ws='pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR wireshark'
```

and run `ws` for Wireshark.

Comment: He gives me the same message !

Comment: @KatiAis try now, I updated

Comment: Look that <br>http://www2.0zz0.com/2016/03/21/01/646882356.png

Answer (score 0):

From your host linux you can:

$ ssh mininet@mininet_ip -X

and then you can run wireshark on your host machine.

OR

$ startx # on mininet