# Using GUI on ssh session

Tags: 14.04, ssh, gui

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't use GUI applications over SSH. I followed several tutorials ([first one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456689/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-when-attempting-to-run-naut), [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187159/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-gtk-warning-cannot-open-d)) online but I can't still fix it. Below is the process I followed.

1. I first installed Ubuntu 14.04 command line version only, I later realized I might need GUI over SSH then I installed ubuntu-desktop.
2. `sudo apt get update`
3. Set X11 Forwarding in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to yes
4. Restart the server.
5. SSH using `ssh -X me@server`
6. Using normal user, I started `gedit` using `gedit`

But I am getting the error below.

> error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
>
> (gedit:1771): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I tried fixing it but to no success. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: What OS is the local machine, and what X server are you running on it?

Comment: @steeldriver, my current OS is MAC OS Sierra, I don't know if I need X server on Mac. Are you saying I need one and if yes can you give me a reference on how to do this.

Comment: TBH I don't know anything about MAC - I *think* that you need to run xquartz, but I'm not sure about that. See for example [ssh -X without/with using xquartz](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162572/ssh-x-without-with-using-xquartz)