# Gstreamer error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, gstreamer

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the Windows 10 PC with Windows Subsystem for Linux turned on so that I can run Linux on the PC. I tried to use Gstreamer-1.0 then.

When running the line:

```
gst-launch-1.0  videotestsrc ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I get the error:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
```

And then it does nothing. What must I do to fix this?

For extra info here is the complete 'code':

```
gst-launch-1.0  videotestsrc ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1773): gst_xv_image_sink_open (): /GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage:
Could not open display (null)
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:05.400472100
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: I would state the best option, being most secure and not altering your root user environment in any manner that may break your system, you should simply pass the environment variable in your invocation of sudo by setting the --preserve-env=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR switch.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108167/1101518) worked for me

To make it easy - more explained the new booting of my system.

After all explanations here I came to the result - and "env" in terminal said already that is right for these session:

These two rows to use the environment variable:

for the tmp behavior I have chosen:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.cache/xdgr
```

For setting the environment variable:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$PATH:~/.cache/xdgr
```

After closing the terminal and a new open for the recall of env they tells:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
```